# Fancybox always on bottom

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox for my new project. I want fancybox iframe to be on bottom of the page when I scroll.

I tried variation of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197877/how-to-position-fancybox-on-top) here but it doesn't work for me.

Also if someone knows better plugin. Requirements are, iframe, positioning, and most important that it can be in a mod that i can still work on parent page if iframe opened

thank u very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was a waste of time trying to dock fancybox :D

Instead I used the solution with only divs from [always visible divs](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/creating_always_visible_div_using_css.aspx). Ok so if u use this you will get the problem with IE so just apply [ie solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545715/always-ensuring-that-div-tag-is-at-top-of-page-using-jquery). Come to think about it, you dont need plugins if you are using iframes.